# SDL library in linux

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, sdl

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main(void) {

    SDL_Surface *Hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *Screen = NULL;

    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    return 0;
}
```

But it happens that the compiler says that:

> undefined reference to SDL_Init

I dont know why this is happening. I'm using Debian Mint and Code::Blocks. Could you Help me?

Comment: You need to link against the SDL library with `-lsdl` (at the end of your `g++` or `clang++` line). There's some way to set that in Code::Blocks, but I haven't used that for a long time (I use emacs and old fashioned makefiles if I need to build something)

Comment: What's the exact compiler command you're using?  You have a library or include path issue, I suspect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to this. I used to work with windows and I've trade for Linux a few days ago to learn more about this "backstage". Could you please explain to me what is the "compiler command" and how can I set it up for this?

Comment: I don't know how you do it in Code::Blocks - like I said, it's several years since I last used that, and currently I don't use any IDE, just the basic editor and basic debugger. I'm happy with that. But there is almost certainly some setting for "additional libraries" or something along those lines. Or google for "Configure SDL build in Code::Blocks", and someone will have written down how to do that.

Comment: Maybe this works: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/codeblocks/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't got `-lSDL` on your link line.

`sdl-config` returns the compile and link flags for your installation of SDL.

Assuming the program is `sdl.cpp`

```
g++ -o sdl `sdl-config --cflags` sdl.cpp `sdl-config --libs`
```

Should give you the correct flags.

Comment: `pkg-config` is a bit more general.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project and then build options and select your project name.

Now go to the `linker` setting and type the following lines in the `Other Linker options` textbox:

> -lSDLmain 
>   -lSDL

`SDL` also requires command line arguments in the main function so you should change

```
int main(void)
```

to

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Now compile your project and it should work.