# no finding SDL library on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, find, sdl

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main(void) {

    SDL_Surface *Hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *Screen = NULL;

    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    return 0;
}
```

But it happens that the compiler says that:

> ```
> undefined reference to SDL_Init
> ```

I dont know why this is happening. I'm using Debian Mint and Code::Blocks. Could you Help me?
I have downloaded the sdl libraries from the official website.

The compiler is finding the library, he is just not getting to find those functions. I dont know why. The functions are on the file.

```
/*
    SDL - Simple DirectMedia Layer
    Copyright (C) 1997-2012 Sam Lantinga

    This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
    modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
    License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
    version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

    This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
    Lesser General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
    License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA

    Sam Lantinga
    slouken@libsdl.org
*/

/** @file SDL.h
 *  Main include header for the SDL library
 */

#ifndef _SDL_H
#define _SDL_H

#include "SDL_main.h"
#include "SDL_stdinc.h"
#include "SDL_audio.h"
#include "SDL_cdrom.h"
#include "SDL_cpuinfo.h"
#include "SDL_endian.h"
#include "SDL_error.h"
#include "SDL_events.h"
#include "SDL_loadso.h"
#include "SDL_mutex.h"
#include "SDL_rwops.h"
#include "SDL_thread.h"
#include "SDL_timer.h"
#include "SDL_video.h"
#include "SDL_version.h"

#include "begin_code.h"
/* Set up for C function definitions, even when using C++ */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/** @file SDL.h
 *  @note As of version 0.5, SDL is loaded dynamically into the application
 */

/** @name SDL_INIT Flags
 *  These are the flags which may be passed to SDL_Init() -- you should
 *  specify the subsystems which you will be using in your application.
 */
/*@{*/
#define SDL_INIT_TIMER      0x00000001
#define SDL_INIT_AUDIO      0x00000010
#define SDL_INIT_VIDEO      0x00000020
#define SDL_INIT_CDROM      0x00000100
#define SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK   0x00000200
#define SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE    0x00100000  /**< Don't catch fatal signals */
#define SDL_INIT_EVENTTHREAD    0x01000000  /**< Not supported on all OS's */
#define SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING 0x0000FFFF
/*@}*/

/** This function loads the SDL dynamically linked library and initializes 
 *  the subsystems specified by 'flags' (and those satisfying dependencies)
 *  Unless the SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE flag is set, it will install cleanup
 *  signal handlers for some commonly ignored fatal signals (like SIGSEGV)
 */
extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_Init(Uint32 flags);

/** This function initializes specific SDL subsystems */
extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_InitSubSystem(Uint32 flags);

/** This function cleans up specific SDL subsystems */
extern DECLSPEC void SDLCALL SDL_QuitSubSystem(Uint32 flags);

/** This function returns mask of the specified subsystems which have
 *  been initialized.
 *  If 'flags' is 0, it returns a mask of all initialized subsystems.
 */
extern DECLSPEC Uint32 SDLCALL SDL_WasInit(Uint32 flags);

/** This function cleans up all initialized subsystems and unloads the
 *  dynamically linked library.  You should call it upon all exit conditions.
 */
extern DECLSPEC void SDLCALL SDL_Quit(void);

/* Ends C function definitions when using C++ */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#include "close_code.h"

#endif /* _SDL_H */
```

How can I link it and to what? I've tried to a file from the SDL folder with extension .so and .a. None of them made this work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDL library in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846268/sdl-library-in-linux)

Comment: You've already ASKED exactly the same question...

Comment: Oh, good days with SDL, brings me back to my first programming class a few years ago :D

Comment: sorry Mats Petersson, Its because nobody is answering and I'm getting very frustrated with this question

Comment: I did answer - I told you exactly what is wrong - just not a step by step instruction how to fix it. And I even googled for you and posted a link...

Comment: Down voted for posting same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your libraries. In your code::blocks compiler under project->build options-> linker -> other linker options, you need to link the SDL libraries by typing -lSDL in the text field. The same for any other library. Like for SDL_image you need to type in -lSDL_image.

For future reference:

1. for SDL GFX use -lSDL_gfx
2. OpenGl use: -lGLU && -lGL
3. DevIL for OpenGL 
            *in this order:
              -lIL,
              -lILU,
              -lILUT

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your SDL/SDL.h file is saved in the same directory of your .c file.

Comment: Why does it have to be on the same folder? Even if that's that way it doesn't work. I'm really starting to be frustrated with linux.. bah

Answer (score 0):

Where is the **SDL** folder located? It must be located in the same folder as the file you are compiling. 
Equally important, the file **SDL.h** must be inside the **SDL** folder. 
 If everything is intact and you are still receiving that error, open up the SDL.h file and look for the function **SDL_Init**.  
The problem should be resolved with any of those suggestions.

### Update

Right above this section

```
#ifndef _SDL_H
```

put

```
#undef _SDL_H
```

there and compile it again. 
The section you posted is surrounded by a conditional; so, it might not execute at all. Putting the new code there allows the compiler to evaluate that section you pasted. 
That'll might help you. 
 
Hope the explanation is clear and the answer helps.

Comment: But "undefined reference to SDL_init" is a linker warning - it means that the -lsdl is missing from the linking line - just like I wrote in a comment in the previous question (exactly identical question, just different in title). But since I didn't know how to set it up in Code::Blocks, I just left it as a comment. That was obviously not good enough.

Comment: Yeah; it's a linker warning. However, the compiler shouldn't have a problem if the files are located properly.

Comment: But the compiler is finding the library, he is just not getting to find those functions. I dont know why. Here is the declaration of the functions:

extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_Init(Uint32 flags);
extern DECLSPEC int SDLCALL SDL_InitSubSystem(Uint32 flags);
extern DECLSPEC void SDLCALL SDL_QuitSubSystem(Uint32 fla
extern DECLSPEC Uint32 SDLCALL SDL_WasInit(Uint32 flags);
extern DECLSPEC void SDLCALL SDL_Quit(void);


How can I link it and to what? I've tried to a file from the SDL folder with extension .so and .a. None of them made this work. I'm really desperate

Comment: Include this update in your question so it can be seen better.

Comment: I've updated. The path of the folder is the default from the "apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev": _/usr/include/SDL_.

I already put the library on the same folder of the program, tried to compile with -lsdl, i've configured code::blocks to look on the folder SDL/Include, and nothing seems to work..

Comment: DIdn't work, sir. I'm spending so much time in this... this should be simple and I'm not getting it. This time I could be learning how to program